# Update CGridView when a dropdown value changes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have a CGridView  with columns from a table `"product" => {'product_id','category_id',...}`
I have another table `"category" => {'category_id','category_name'}`

`category_id` is the FK in the `product` table.

Now i want a dropdown list of the category table and on selecting a particular value the CGridView of product should be updated to show only the rows with that `category_id`. 
I also need the column filtering/sorting for the CGridView to work (using AJAX).

I was able to refresh the CGridView when a value is selected from the dropdown, however i am not
able to send the category_id with the 'data' for the CGridView: 
 
`clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.cat_dropdown').change(function(){
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('order-grid', {
        data: $(this).serialize(),
    });
    return false;
});
");`

The `data: $(this).serialize()` sends only the values that are present in the filtering text fields of the CGridView.
How do i append the category_id with it?

If the above method is not the right one, please suggest an alternative method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i finally did it. I dont know if the solution is optimal or not, but it works.
Any comments welcome.

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('yiiGridView.update', "
  $.fn.yiiGridView.update = function(id, options) {
    var settings = $.fn.yiiGridView.settings[id];
    var data = {
        'product[category_id]': $('.cat_dropdown option:selected').val(),
    };
    options = $.extend({
         type: 'GET',
         data: data,
         success: function(data,status) {
             $.each(settings.ajaxUpdate, function() {
                 $('#'+this).replaceWith($(data).find('#'+this));
                 });
                 if(settings.afterUpdate != undefined)
                     settings.afterUpdate(id, data);
                 },
                 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                 }
             }, options || {});
    if(settings.beforeUpdate != undefined)
        settings.beforeUpdate(id);
    $.ajax(options);
    };
 ");

The above solution, however, needs the `category_id` in the columns option of CGridView. If it is removed the filtering on other columns does not work.
If it is kept the filtering on other columns work, but the `category_id` is present in the grid( which is not required)
Need a way to hide the `category_id` column in CGridView or some other solution.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add the drop menu to CGridView, nothing more, eg.:

```
array('name' => 'category_id', 'value' => 'Categories::model()->getCategoryName($data->category_id)', 'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Categories::model()->getCategoryObj(), 'category_id', 'category_name')),
```

Looking at the above, you will need to add two methods to your Categories class:

getCategoryName
getCategoryObj

Read this:

http://www.mattiressler.com/customising-cgridview-select-menu/

http://www.mattiressler.com/using-class-properties-to-minimise-database-queries/

You don't need to add any javascript  :-)